# Switching between 2 nodes in ROS with a 3rd script

Tags: python, ros

I finally archieved my goal to implement a line detecting algorithm to my robot. Now i want to combine my 2 different scripts.
The first one is the line detection function. whenever the robot sees a black line in its path it dirigates to the black line.
the second function is basically to control the robot with a joycon from the /joy node

My question now is a bit more theoretical:
I want to create a third node. In this node you have basically a subscriber for the joy node. And when you press a certain button (im thinking on the Triangle Button on the PS5 controller) it switches the modes.
So basically when i start the launch file, it starts in mode 1. When i press the triangle button, it changes to mode 2 and back.
The switch node publishes a variable (either 1 or 2) and the other 2 files subscribe to this and when the other number is published, the node stays in idle

About my 2 existing scripts:
Both are defined as classes.
in the first one, "line_detection.py":

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, CompressedImage
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
from std_msgs.msg import Int32
class LineDetector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rate = rospy.Rate(rospy.get_param("/rate/lineDetector"))
        self.bridge = CvBridge()
        self.mode= rospy.Subscriber("/mode_topic",Int32)
        self.image_sub_rpi =rospy.Subscriber("/raspicam_node/image/compressed", CompressedImage, self.image_callback_compressed)
        self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/camera/image_raw", Image, self.image_callback_raw)
        self.image_pub = rospy.Publisher("processed_image", Image, queue_size=1)
        self.image_debug_pub = rospy.Publisher("debug_image", Image, queue_size=1)

    def image_callback_raw(self, msg):
        try:
            cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, "passthrough")
            self.process_image(cv_image)
        except CvBridgeError as e:
            rospy.logerr("Raw Error")
            rospy.logerr(e)
    def image_callback_compressed(self, msg):
        try:
            np_arr = np.frombuffer(msg.data, np.uint8)
            image_np = cv2.imdecode(np_arr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            self.process_image(image_np)
        except CvBridgeError as e:
            rospy.logerr("Compressed Error")
            rospy.logerr(e)
    def process_image(self, cv_image):
        low_b=np.uint8([51,51,51])
        high_b=np.uint8([0,0,0])
        cv_image = cv2.resize(cv_image, (256,256), interpolation =cv2.INTER_AREA)
        mask = cv2.inRange(cv_image,high_b,low_b)
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask,1,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

        if len(contours) > 0:
            c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
            M=cv2.moments(c)
            if M["m00"] !=0 :
                cx= int(M["m10"]/M["m00"])
                cy= int(M["m01"]/M["m00"])

                print("CX: "+ str(cx)+"CY: "+str(cy))
                if cx>160:
                    print("Turn Left")
                if cx< 160 and cx > 96:
                    print("On Track!")
                if cx <=96:
                    print("Turn Right")
                cv2.line(cv_image,(128,256),(128,0),(0,0,255),2)
                cv2.line(cv_image,(0,128),(256,128),(0,0,255),2)
                cv2.circle(cv_image,(cx,cy), 5, (255,255,255), -1)
        else:
            print("No line in sight. Dang!")
        cv_message = self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(cv_image,"passthrough")
        cv_debug = self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(mask,"passthrough")
        self.image_pub.publish(cv_message)
        self.image_debug_pub.publish(cv_debug)
    def run(self):
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            self.rate.sleep()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('coole_linien')
    line_detector = LineDetector()
    rospy.spin()
```

and second my motor_control:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy
import numpy as np

class MotorControl:
    def __init__(self):
        self.controls_sub = rospy.Subscriber("joy",Joy,self.control)
         
    def control(self):
        if self.axes[5] <= 0.95 and self.axes[5] > 0.75:
            print("Modus 1") 
        elif self.axes[5] <= 0.75 and self.axes[5] > 0.2:
            print("Modus 2") 
        elif self.axes[5] <= 0.2 and self.axes[5] > -0.2:
            print("Modus 3") 
        elif self.axes[5] <= -0.2 and self.axes[5] > -1:
            print("Modus 5") 
        elif self.axes[5] == -1:
            print("Modus 6") 
        else:

            if self.axes[2] <= 0.95 and self.axes[2] > 0.75:
                print("Modus 7")   
            elif self.axes[2] <= 0.75 and self.axes[2] > 0.2:
                print("Modus 8")
            elif self.axes[2] <= 0.2 and self.axes[2] > -0.2:
                print("Modus 9") 
            elif self.axes[2] <= -0.2 and self.axes[2] >= -1:
                print("Modus 10") 
            else:
                print("Modus 0") 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node("control")
    mc=MotorControl()
    rospy.spin()
```

How can i implement my idea in the functions? am i thinking too complex?
Is it easy to achieve or will it be way too complicated for a little extra feature that isnt really necessary?

Thank you for your suggestions.
Sincerely Pascal

i have no really idea how to implement this. I tried creating a third script which changes modes when pressing triangle, but i dont know how to implement it in the other functions

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy
from std_msgs.msg import Int32

current_mode = 1

def switch_callback(data):
    global current_mode
    if data.buttons[3] == 1:
        if current_mode == 1:
            current_mode = 2

        else:
            current_mode = 1

    mode_msg =Int32()
    mode_msg.data = current_mode
    mode_pub.publish(mode_msg)

def switch():
    global mode_pub
    rospy.init_node('cooler_switch',anonymous=False)
    rospy.Subscriber("joy",Joy,switch_callback)
    mode_pub = rospy.Publisher("mode_topic",Int32, queue_size=10)
    rospy.spin()
if __name__=='__main__':
    switch()
```